# ¿Qué significa "non-static variable [name] cannot be referenced from a static context"?

Tags: java

Estoy en este momento diseñando el proyecto final del curso sobre Estructuras de Datos en Java que estoy llevando y decidimos realizar una especie de visor de películas.

Me corresponde realizar la parte del login, ya que el mismo podrá diferenciar si es un usuario y/o administrador y en base a ello cargar la interfaz específica.

Sin embargo al momento de validar los datos ingresados en el campo texto tengo el error *"non-static variable [name] cannot be referenced from a static context"*

A continuación el detalle de la clase Admins, que contiene los datos de los administradores, y el detalle del JFrame login_pop

```
package popcornflix;

public class Admins {    
public String username, password, email; 
private int id;

public Admins(String username, String password, String email, int id) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Admins{" + "username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", email=" + email + ", id=" + id + '}';
}
}
```

Lo anterior corresponde a la clase que contiene los valores de los administradores. A continuación los datos del método donde tengo el login, destaco que está dentro de una clase diferente.

```
private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    if(user.getText().equals(Admins.username) && 
password.getText().equals(Admins.password)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido administrador");
        //llamar a la ventana de administrador
        //
        dispose(); //limpia la ventana
        // establecer la ventana de administrador en visible (true)
        //.setVisible(true);

    }else if(user.getText().equals(Client.username) && 
password.getText().equals(Client.password)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido a POPCORN FLIX");
        //llamar a la ventana de usuario
        //
        dispose(); //limpia la ventana
        // establecer la ventana de user en visible (true)
        //.setVisible(true);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contraseña o Usuario 
inválidos"); 
    }                    
}                                              

private void passwordKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
   if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
      if(user.getText().equals(Admins.username) && 
password.getText().equals(Admins.password)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido administrador");
        //llamar a la ventana de administrador
        //
        dispose(); //limpia la ventana
        // establecer la ventana de administrador en visible (true)
        //.setVisible(true);

    }else if(user.getText().equals(Client.username) && 
password.getText().equals(Client.password)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido a POPCORN FLIX");
        //llamar a la ventana de usuario
        //
        dispose(); //limpia la ventana
        // establecer la ventana de user en visible (true)
        //.setVisible(true);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contraseña o Usuario 
inválidos"); 
    }                    
}
}
```

En la línea

```
if(user.getText().equals(Admins.username) && password.getText().equals(Admins.password)){
```

es donde se marca el error que comento en la pregunta principal ¿cómo podría hacer para que este error no sucede y que de igual manera el if valide lo ingresado en el campo user y password?

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo estás tratando de obtener un dato de tu clase Admins(como anexo: las clases se deben escribir en singular). En tú codigo escríbes `Admins.username` y `Admins.password`, pero intentas acceder a ellos como si fuera una variable static.

Se debe conocer la diferencia entre una variable de instancia con una de static. Las primera se invoca sobre una instancia de una clase (objeto), es decir, `Clase miclase = new Clase();`, y las static no necesitan una invocación por instancia.

Por ejemplo: Si escribimos una clase llamada conexion con un método estatic

```
public class Conexion{

      public static void conectar(){
             // Codigo de conexion
            }    
}
```

Ahora que tenemos un método static, ésta se pueden compartir en otras clases sin crear una instancia como: `Conexion con = new Conexion();`

Ejemplo:

```
public class Modificar {

        private void actualizar(){
            //Se invoca el método static
              Conexion.conectar();
              }    
}
```

Para resolver tu problema, necesitas crear una instancia de tu clase Admins para que en tiempo de ejecución pueda reservar un espacio de memoria, de lo contrario cada instancia se sobreescribira y no se desea.

Así lograrás algo como

```
Admins admin = new Admins();
String username = admin.getUsername();
String password = admins.getPassword();
```

Dependiendo de donde tengas tu información almacenada, así obtendrás la información que necesitas.

Saludos.